# Arduino error arduino first defined here, how to fix it?

Tags: arduino

I am facing the error *arduino first defined here* while trying to compile my code,
I think that the reason is that my class needs to have access to some variables
that are defined in the header of my main skecht.ino. Simplifying I have something like
this

main .ino

```
#include "myLibt.h"

setup(){
//setup something
}
loop(){
//loop something
}
```

myLibs.h looks like

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int x;
int y;
int z;
```

then I have my class that needs to access x, y and z from *myLibs.h*, if I do as below, including
*myLibs.h* in the class, while compiling I get the error mentioned (*arduino first defined here*)
for each of the variables of *myLibs.h* that I use. (Notice that the operations of my class
are just examples)

```
#incldue "myLibs.h"
class A{

int a;
int b;

void m1();
  void m2(){

    x = a + x;
    z = b * z;
  }
}
```

Why do I have that error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Also posted at http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=475314. Instead of cross posting you should have taken a moment to compile your demonstration code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue consisted on having the variables `x, y` and `z` on my libs.h, moving them to the class A itself or creating a new extra class where class A have access to fixed the issue